# api key, daily limit, free vs. pricing model for javascript v3

Tags: google-maps

I have about 300 domains that use google maps.  Each has a separate API key.  One of them gave me an error saying incorrect key, then following up I now understand that v3 has no key and an API limit of 25k maps per day.

Is this 25k per account or per website?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Some parts of the Google API require the API key and others do not when using the JavaScript API.  For the parts that do not require the key the limit is per client IP unless you use your API key.  Otherwise, I believe the usage limits are per key so if each website has a different key, then you should be OK.

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits

Comment: Thanks Pete, that should not be a problem for me then.  I couldn't find the 'per client IP' reference anywhere in the faq.

Comment: I edited my answer because some parts of the API require use of the key and some do not.